# Is it possible to create a custom state for use in a StateListDrawable?

Tags: android, state, drawable

They have states for things like pressed, focused, disabled, but is it possible to create custom states so it could reflect some of my own custom criteria?

For example, say you have a list of names. Some people fall into a certain category that should be visually represented differently.  These people's rows would then have a different state and background drawable.

Comment: Although probably possible, if these states only apply to the views in a specific listview, why would you want to add custom states like that? Just handle the logic yourself and set your drawables accordingly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [article](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/uqr2BNI7NZo/discussion) shows how to do it.

Comment: They say that it does not work on Android 4.0.2 (a bottom post there).